# Validation in MVP pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I am creating a program which utilizes MVP architecture.  Please tell me which is the best place to write the validation. Someone told me that the code in presenter should only contains logic to handle events raised from the GUI and format values collected from the model so that  view can display values without any overhear. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using Winforms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: the application will be developed using winforms

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217752/in-mvp-where-to-write-validations